# How do I display results?

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to HTML and Javascript. I am trying to make a simple website that counts up yes and no votes. I want to display the number of votes for each. The results should be updated after each vote. When I enter a vote, it gets updated for a split second then reverts back to 0,0,0. How do I resolve this?

```js
var yes = 0;
var no = 0;

function clickYes() {
  yes++;
  alert("You pressed yes");
  refreshResults();
}

function clickNo() {
  no++;
  alert("You pressed no");
  refreshResults();
}

function refreshResults() {
  var results = document.getElementById('results');
  results.innerHTML = "Total: " + (yes + no);
  results.innerHTML += "<br>Yes: " + yes;
  results.innerHTML += "<br>No: " + no;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="voteCount.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<head>
  <h1>This Website Counts Up Votes</h1>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="userInput">
    <h2>Yes or No?</h2>
    <form>
      <button type="radio" onclick="clickYes()" id="yesbutton">Yes</button>
      <button type="radio" onclick="clickNo()" id="nobutton">No</button>
    </form>
  </div>

  <h3 id="results">
      <script>
      refreshResults();
      </script>
    </h3>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi, In order to store the votes you have to use database, I prefer you to use some back end technologies as well like php, .net or java.

Comment: You haven't closed the `</body>`. You cannot have `<h1>` inside `<head>`!

Comment: Are you going to conside any server side script and DB to store the count ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is **button is reloading** the page. Either give `type="button"` or you need to prevent the default event. Also there are few issues:

1. You haven't closed the `</body>`.
2. You cannot have `<h1>` inside `<head>`!
3. Button's type should be either of `button`, `submit` or `reset`, which defaults to `submit`.
4. You cannot have a `<script>` tag, that way how you have used it.

**Working Snippet** with the `alert`.

```js
var yes = 0;
var no = 0;

function clickYes() {
  yes++;
  alert("You pressed yes");
  refreshResults();
}

function clickNo() {
  no++;
  alert("You pressed no");
  refreshResults();
}

function refreshResults() {
  var results = document.getElementById('results');
  results.innerHTML = "Total: " + (yes + no);
  results.innerHTML += "<br>Yes: " + yes;
  results.innerHTML += "<br>No: " + no;
}
```

```html
<h1>This Website Counts Up Votes</h1>
<div id="userInput">
  <h2>Yes or No?</h2>
  <form>
    <button type="button" onclick="clickYes()" id="yesbutton">Yes</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="clickNo()" id="nobutton">No</button>
  </form>
</div>

<h3 id="results"></h3>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi Try to remove script tag from your html file.
its working fine for me.

Hope this helps...

```js
var yes = 0;
var no = 0;

function clickYes() {
  yes++;
  
  refreshResults();
}

function clickNo() {
  no++;
  
  refreshResults();
}

function refreshResults() {
  var results = document.getElementById('results');
  results.innerHTML = "Total: " + (yes + no);
  results.innerHTML += "<br>Yes: " + yes;
  results.innerHTML += "<br>No: " + no;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="voteCount.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<head>
  <h1>This Website Counts Up Votes</h1>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="userInput">
    <h2>Yes or No?</h2>
    <form>
      <button type="radio" onclick="clickYes()" id="yesbutton">Yes</button>
      <button type="radio" onclick="clickNo()" id="nobutton">No</button>
    </form>
  </div>

  <h3 id="results">
      

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function refreshResults() {
    var results = document.getElementById('results');
    var output = "Total: " + (yes + no);
        output += "<br>Yes: " + yes;
        output += "<br>No: " + no;
    results.innerHTML = output;
}
```